# Calculating Overlapping Time Intervals in SQL between several users

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

after quite some time spent online to try to find an answer to my problem I decided to post it here.

I have a table which contains intervals of time during which some resources are not available. I would like to extract all time interval in which all resources are not available.

With the example below, I would have: start: 2018-11-16 12:30:00, end: 2018-11-16 12:45:00

```
Start                   End                     Resource
-------------------     -------------------     ----------  
2018-11-15 12:00:00     2018-11-15 13:00:00     resource A
2018-11-15 12:00:00     2018-11-15 13:00:00     resource B
2018-11-15 12:30:00     2018-11-15 14:00:00     resource C
2018-11-15 12:00:00     2018-11-15 12:45:00     resource D
2018-11-18 12:00:00     2018-11-18 13:00:00     resource A
2018-11-19 11:40:00     2018-11-19 12:20:00     resource B
2018-11-15 16:00:00     2018-11-15 17:00:00     resource D
```

Would someone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  This is so cumbersome prior to 8.0 that it may not be worth attempting.

Comment: Well, actually I use postgresql, the version 9.5.

Comment: There is no time interval in your sample data when no resources are available. During 2018-11-16 12:30:00 to 2018-11-16 14:00:00 only resource C is unavailable

Comment: Made a mistake with my sample. I just corrected it.

Comment: I forgot to ask but how do we now how many "all resources" are or is that dynamic  and something that is part of the query and if so do we know all resources will be represented in the table?

Comment: The number of resources can be get in an other table. So not all resource will be represented in this table.

Comment: So it means that if not all the resources are present in this table the query doesn't need to be executed since there are resources that have never been unavailable by default? The logic for this situation isn't very clear, what does really" all resources" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of resources (or it can be calculated) and there's no overlapping Start/End range for a resource (i.e. you got clean data):

```
select Start, "End"
from
 ( -- calculate a Cumulative Sum to get the count of resources unavailable at any point in time
   select Start,
      lead(Start) over (order by Start,  x) as "End", 
      sum(x) over (order by Start,  x rows unbounded preceding) as cnt
   from
    ( -- combine starts & ends into a single table and assigne +/-1 to each row
      select Start,  1 as x
      from tab
      union all 
      select "End", -1 as x
      from tab
    ) as dt
 ) as dt
where cnt = 4 -- find the row where all resources are unavailable
--  where cnt = (select count(*) from resources)
```